# Scala: Pattern matching vs if-else

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Moving to Scala from Java, one sees usage of pattern matching for branching out the code, something achieved with if-else in Java. But Scala offers if-else too.

Going by code readability, I personally prefer if-else. Also, google search tells that bytecode generated for pattern matching is much bigger.

So under what circumstances one should prefer one over other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matching is much more powerful than `if/else`, and than java's `switch` statement.
You can elegantly check object types with it:

```
foo match {
   case i: Int => i
   case f: Double => Math.round(f*100) 
   case s: String => s.toInt 
}
```

You can deconstruct complex objects:

```
foo match {
   case SomeObject(AnotherObject(_, _, bar), _, _, baz) => bar -> baz
   case head :: tail => head -> tail
   case Seq(a, b, c, _, _ rest@_*) => (a,b,c) -> rest
}
```

You can use custom matchers and deconstructors by implementing `unapply` and `unapplySeq`:

```
foo match {
   case PrimeNumber(next, _@_*) => print(s"$foo is prime, next is $next")
   case Compound(primes@_*) => print(s"$foo is compound: ${primes.mkString("*")}=$foo"
}
```

You can use them as a shortcut declaring a partial function to deconstruct parameters:

```
   stuff.zipWithIndex.collect { case (foo, idx) if idx % 2 == 0 => foo }
```

Etc. (many, may uses). I am not sure about the size of the byte code ... and frankly, don't know why I would care. In cases where these kinds of differences in size matter, I would probably be writing "C" or assembly anyway.

Comment: You can not check object types, pattern matching works in runtime, and types doesn't exists at runtime. And such checks are a bad practice since they break parametricity. Since OP is new to the language we shouldn't introduce he / she to those.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you gotta pick one: either you cannot do it or you can but it is bad practice :D Hint: it's actually neither. You very much CAN do it (and types absolutely DO exist in run time), and there are plenty of legitimate and idiomatic uses for it. Also "parametricity" isn't even a word, so you shouldn't be afraid to "break" it.

Comment: It is not a type check, is a class check, types do not exist at runtime, only classes. You can not match for `List[Int]` vs `List[String]` you can only match on the `List` class. - And having to do those is considered a [bad practice](https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html) - Finally, the word [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity) does exists.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Class _is_ a (kind of) type. Yes, I am aware of type erasure. That does not mean that you cannot check for types at run time, just that you cannot check for _type parameters_ (you actually _can_ too, just in a more complex way). Checking for type information at run time _may_ be a bad practice or it may be not, just like pretty much any other mechanism (consider using mutable state for instance). Blankly stating that it is "bad" is just ... well ... wrong :)

Comment: Classes are not types, they are different; it is just that creating a class also creates a type _(or a type constructor if generic)_. When I say that you can not check for a type in runtime I mean that the JVM doesn't provide a native way to do that. Yes the **Scala** stdlib provide us with things like `TypeTags` that could be used to retrieve such information in runtime, but much similar to runtime reflection _(very different than mutability)_ the language provides alternatives to most common use cases of those features as such I still consider showing them to newcomers a bad idea.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you are arguing semantics here. "Creating a class also creates a type" – yes, and all instances of that class will have that type, and all objects of that type will be instances of that class. So, when referring to an object, saying that it is an instance of `String` or that it has type `String` are equivalent statements. Note also, that I have never showed any type tags to newcomers, even though I wholeheartedly disagree with you that it is a bad idea :)

Comment: @Dima Given `val s = ""` what is the class corresponding to `s.type`?

Comment: @MarioGalic Check out the conversation above. Did I ever say that all types are classes or have a corresponding class? Having said that, you still _can_ write `case foo: s.type => ???` in a match clause ... (not sure _why_ you would want to do that ... or why `s.type` is a thing in the first place, but that's a separate topic).

Comment: `case _: s.type =>` is a reference check via `eq`, as is `isInstanceOf[s.type]`.

Comment: @MarioGalic I know :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Who are you to say whether or not OP is qualified to handle a fundamental part of the Scala language??? Pattern-matching is a very powerful tool, and TypeTags allow its mechanics. It is a designed feature of the language! And is referenced in almost all Scala books within the first few chapters. It is a great tool to learn, if you're that paranoid about performance, don't use the JVM, virtualization is just not right for that.

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer it seems you do not even understand what I am talking about, so let me try to make it cleaner. - 1) I am not against **pattern matching** I never said that, I am against class checks, because those break the parametricity property, and because they are confusing since they look like they are checking for types when it is not the case, this has been a source of confusion for me, for people I know and for people on the internet. - 2) TypeTags do not allow that mechanism, **TypeTags** allow you to extract type information in runtime, and it doesn't work with pattern matching.

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer 3)  not sure what performance has to do with anything I said. 4) I did not way that OP was not qualified to understand anything, I said that **TypeTags** are not really something that should be shown to newbies to the language, which is different.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I passionately disagree with you. And I think Martin Odersky would as well. Unfortunately, I don't think this is the proper forum to discuss this much further, and while I don't understand your point of view, it is one you clearly are passionate about, and I respect that. Pattern matching cannot do everything, and type erasure is a product of using the JVM. But I have yet to see an example of how teaching someone pattern matching in Scala has led to complicating things. https://www.artima.com/articles/the-point-of-pattern-matching-in-scala

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer you are still confusing **pattern matching** with a class checks, the second one is one of the things that the pattern matching syntax allows us to do, but is one I firmly believe should not be used for reasons stated above _(also at that point the name is wrong, since we are not longer inspecting a pattern but accessing metadata from the runtime system)_. But that doest mean that all forms of pattern matching are bad, I never said that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez These are high level features, that cover high level abstractions based on the limitations of the JVM. TypeTags are Scalas solution to help address type erasure, and Scala 3 furthers this idea by including an entire file dedicated to the AST representations of the class structures and types, in an effort to eliminate some of the restrictions caused by type erasure. The Scala language is built using TypeTags, so to argue that pattern matching on these types is bad seems quite a strange point, I would love to see some evidence of that in practice to supports that view.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The limitations on pattern matching lie in the fact that type erasure exists on the JVM. Not all Java is necessarily Scala, but all Scala is Java. Limitations on parameters and parameterization exist entirely because of the limitations of the lowest common denominator, Java. For parameterized JAVA types, this limitation cannot be overcome, at least not without reflection. For Scala types, however, TypeTags allow for almost any type to be matched, JVM limitations withstanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230463/discussion-between-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez-and-randomness-slayer).

Answer (score 2):

Java also offers `switch` so a similar question arises in Java as well. Your personal preference for `switch` vs `if` in Java will help inform the choice of `match` vs `if` in Scala.

Scala `match` allows the following:

1. Multiple tests on the same value
2. Testing type and structure as well as value
3. Extraction of values during the test
4. Cleaner and more readable code

If you don't need any of these, then `if` is probably a better choice.

Also remember that the size of the bytecode is not a great measure of performance because any code where performance matters will be JIT compiled into native code.